# Ember-CLI / Broccoli - How can I remove all comments from source files when building?

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

As in the title - how would one go about removing comments from both JS and CSS files when being compiled though Broccoli.

I am using Broccoli as part of Ember-CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your project you have to set the environment to production, it defaults to development.

`ember build --environment production` will concat, minify and uglify your scripts and css removing all comments.

For more info refer to [this part](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls) of the docs.

Comment: the link to the doc is no more valid, now is http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls